# How to disable notification bar and status bar on lock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have tried the following code but still it will not work properly for me.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following,

```
View view = getWindow().getDecorView();

// Hide the Status bar
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
view.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

// Hide ActionBar
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

or Simply add the style in manifest,

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: I have also tried your given solution earlier but also it not works for me.